# How to recognize element in which item in the gridview

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp

I use the "gridview" not just to "display" but also let users interact with such as 
click the button inside specific item.
Assume my gridview is like this:

```
<Gridview>
  <Gridview.Itemtemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <Image> </Image>
        <Button> </Button>
      </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
</Gridview.Itemtemplate>
```

If I Press the button the button every buttons of all the items in the gridview will do the same thing.
How can we press the button and it know it belong to which item ?

*NOTE that : Press only the button won't trigger the "ItemIsSelected" Event because the item wasn't click, it was the button.

Comment: Most typically you use a MVVM pattern and bind the button to a `ICommand`, then you configure in xaml the `CommandParameter` which will pass the specific bound item to the command. It is too much to write an answer, please research MVVM and ask more specific questions if needed.

Comment: I did use MVVM pattern but only for "clean code" purpose, so I guess what you mean using CommandParameter to pass "which item is it belong" to the "parameter", but how to create a parameter know it belong to which item ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets consider your item is an object of a class `LineItem`. Once the button click is triggered, you can use `sender` from click event argument to get `DataContext` which will be the same object.

> (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext

//Small Sample

MainPage.Xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    x:Name="YourPage"

    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid>
        <GridView x:Name="GridView">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:LineItem">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind  description}"></TextBlock>
                        <Button Content="Action" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.Xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        List<LineItem> MyDictionary = new List<LineItem>();
        public MainPage()
        {
            MyDictionary.Add(new LineItem() { Title = "Item1", description = "Desc1" });
            MyDictionary.Add(new LineItem() { Title = "Item2", description = "Desc2" });
            MyDictionary.Add(new LineItem() { Title = "Item3", description = "Desc3" });
            this.InitializeComponent();
            GridView.ItemsSource = MyDictionary;
        }
        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LineItem clicked_item  =(LineItem)((sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext);
            await (new MessageDialog(clicked_item.Title + " Button is clicked ")).ShowAsync();
        }
    }
    public class LineItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }
```